# Почему в абсолютно пустой сцене Unity мой Пк греется?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я хочу сделать игру на юнити и столкнулся с такой проблемой, в абсолютно пустой сцене в Stats показывается 1.9K tris и 5.5K verts, что же будет если загрузить сцену моделями. Это как должен телефон вывести? Игра ведь на мобилки делается. Я где то находил инфу что проблема в SkyBox но тут 2 вопроса: 1) Неужели Default SkyBox Unity так сильно нагружает систему 2) Как тогда оптимизируются другие игры, неужели не использую SkyBox?

Вот доказательство:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну может быть он у вас греется всегда :) Ну или Unity вообще очень тяжеловесный движок.

Comment: Нет в играх я всегда ставлю ультра настройки графики и нормально выше 40 градусов не поднимаеться

Comment: Откройте диспетчер задач и покажите потребление ресурсов у unity

Comment: Там 21% у ЦП написано

Comment: Просто прикол в том что сцена пустая

Comment: Мне интересно откуда на сцене 2K tris

Comment: 2 тысячи треугольников наверно от скайбокса. Но у вас не в них проблема (если бы у вас компьютер нагревался бы от рендеринга 2 тысяч треугольников то он бы ничего не потянул бы). 20% потребления процессора от unity это в принципе нормально

Comment: Ну компьютер с одним квадратом греется до 57 градусов

Comment: Как отключить SkyBox в моей игре нет необходимости в нем

Comment: Просто в настройках камеры нужно выставить `Clear Flags` -> `Solid Color` также вы можете закрыть окно Scene что должно повысить производительность движка

Comment: Сцена не пустая, а с координатной сеткой и т.п. На unity игры делают ради упрощения разработки, а об оптимизации речь вообще не идет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое количество вершин и лиц - это норма, у вас батчей всего 13. Не из-за этого греется. Сам движок юнити - тяжелый. Попробуйте скомпилировать, и проверить само приложение. Но вообще, любая программа на движке подъедает базовую мощность, равную возможностям этого движка, которые крутятся в ожидании их использования. Главное, чтобы в готовой игре не сильно отличалось потребление ЦП

Скайбокс много потребляет, если он сложный. Обычный - это не проблема

Comment: Хорошо, буду иметь в курсе